# LINQ join scoping

Tags: linq, join

Looks like join cannot use sets defined inside query or am I doing something wrong?

```
from a in new[] {
    new { Id = 1 },
    new { Id = 2 } }

let bees = new[] {
    new { Id = 2 },
    new { Id = 3 } }

join b in bees on a.Id equals b.Id

select 1;
```

This one gives compile time error 'Element "bees" does not exist in the current context.' What's wrong with the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not legal either way you slice it - you cannot declare a range variable "in the middle" of a join - internally the let clause gets translated to a `Select()` statement with an anonymous type - but you cannot use `Select()` either in the middle of the join, you have to move it after the join.

Comment: I see now, thank you. Others who would like to know more about, here's the link describing it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2008/05/21/using-let-in-linq-to-objects.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question - I think it covers things:

[Can i use join with let in linq - c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747272/can-i-use-join-with-let-in-linq-c)

Basically you can only use the let for the query, rather than for joins.

The following does seem to work, but its not as nice:

```
from a in new[] {
    new { Id = 1 },
    new { Id = 2 } }

join b in new[] {
    new { Id = 2 },
    new { Id = 3 } } on a.Id equals b.Id

select 1;
```

Comment: Question you mensioned covers different issue. And I don't have that array defined with let until runtime. But thanks anyway :)